# ##[warning]No valid image label found in agent specification. ,##[error]The remote provider was unable to process the request

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to run a pipeline in Azure DevOps and I get the error:

> ##[warning]No valid image label found in agent specification.
> ,##[error]The remote provider was unable to process the request.

I have been using this YAML pipeline configuration without problems before. Now it shows this error:

[image: Error]

The pipeline definition:

[image: Pipeline definition]

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Ubuntu 18 seems to be out of support in April 2023.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue but I'm using ubuntu-latest. Our pipeline has been working without any issues for a year. We didn't do any changes but it now gives the exact same error. 
I changed to a windows agent and it is working now. 
It's weird.

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in the comment I was also facing the same issue. After one year or so, my pipeline stopped working, although I was using ubuntu-latest.

After changing it to a self-hosted windows agent it started to work again, so I got intrigued.

I checked Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pool?view=azure-pipelines#properties) and they mention:

> To use a Microsoft-hosted pool, omit the name and specify one of the
> available hosted images

The yaml syntax for this is

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
```

As I mentioned, I've been using for one year the syntax **vmImageName** which apparently no longer works.

So, **to fix this issue** you just need to change this part of the code:

```
pool:
  vmImageName: $(vmImageName)
```

for:

```
pool:
  vmImage: $(vmImageName)
```

I also recommend you to use ubuntu-latest rather than specifying a specific version.

I hope it helps with your issue :)